I used a bluetooth earplug on Debian Linux, the sound is not working since unless I switch audio device back and forth. How to fix it?
I have used bluetooth earplugs one time. Since then I have no sound when I reboot the computer (HP laptop with Debian system). If I go to the audio volume panel, select another device then select the first again the sound starts to work.
How to make it work after reboot (without clicking back and forth in the audio settings)?

I had the same issue with lmde (debian mint) base on debian 12 between audio jack and speakers. Sound would not switch automatically to the active or default device. I removed pipewire and installed pulseaudio and also using alsamixer and look if device autoswitch is enabled. Maybe this would apply to bluetooth devices with some additional steps. GL
